# Phalcon - undefined symbol: zend_hash_str_del

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon, server-administration

i already compiled Phalcon framework (version 2.1) for php 5.6 and if i allow the framework in php.ini i got this message.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/phalcon.so' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: zend_hash_str_del in Unknown on line 0
```

compilation works well and without errors

My server setup
Ubuntu
ISPConfig 3
PHP 7.0, PHP 5.6.30

Comment: make sure your `extension=phalcon.so` is loaded after your other extensions

Comment: Which PHP is used by application? Has that PHP included phalconphp?

Comment: Did you compile Phalcon for PHP 5.6 and use with PHP 7.0?

Comment: @Timothy: Yes in ubuntu i have in conf.d folder where php get extensions and it is loaded as last

Comment: @klay No i compiled extension with php 5.6 and using it with 5.6

Comment: @Tpojka It is universal configuration so there is no application yet, but php have not loaded extension  because of error

Comment: You showed 2 versions of PHP. Execute `php -v` command to confirm using v5.6

Comment: i compiling phalcon with 5.6 version, i am quite sure :-)

phpize5.6
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config5.6
make && make install

extension is saved right and shows api 20131223 (i do not know exact version, but php 7 on server have api starting 2015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed. I download clean project from git and manually edit configure script in build folder to link to php5.6, phpize5.6 and add --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config5.6 executables and run classic install from source